# Code using LINQ to SQL classes not compiling after publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I've created simple web project in Visual Studio 2010, .Net 4 which has a couple of sections which insert and retrieve data from a SQL Server db. I've set this up through a LINQ to SQL classes 'CommentaryData.dbml' file. This all works fine if I select 'view in browser' from visual studio, when I publish (file publish to IIS wwwroot folder), the files publish with no errors. But when I then go to view in browser, I see the following compilation error: 
*CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CommentaryDataDataContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*
If I expand the detailed compiler output this is occurring on every line which contains my datacontext: `CommentaryDataDataContext`

I already have `system.data.linq` in my project references and my referenced libraries in my code files look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

I have also tried to comment out all code referencing the datacontext and the project then publishes fine, so I'm sure something to do with LINQ is the issue but as far as I can see I am referencing the correct libraries, any ideas of what I could try to resolve this please?

**Edit**: I have tried adding the assembly manually to the web.config as `<add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>` , that didn't work.

I have also checked System.Data.Linq.dll is present in the bin folder, it is

I also tried to refer explicitly to the namespace prior to each instance of the datacontext, the error message in browser changes to tell me the datacontext doesn't exist in that namespace, but when I look in the designer.cs of the dbml the namespace is correct and matches

**Edit 2:** The only dll that is being created (apart from the system. ones) is that of my main namespace/solution/project: TableauCommentary.dll. If I update 'Items to deploy:' to 'Only files needed to run this application' again it publishes fine, however when trying to view in browser I get a different error:

Parser Error Message: The file '/tcom/CommentaryOutput.aspx.cs' does not exist.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CommentaryOutput.aspx.cs" Inherits="TableauCommentary.CommentaryOutput" %>

Build action on all my code files is set to compile, but it seems the dll files are maybe not being created correctly, and the only reason i was hitting the LINQ error rather than this one before was because the codebehind .cs file was being included in the published location, which it shouldn't need to be.  All the code files including the designer for the dbml were created in the project and use the same namespace, so maybe there should only be one dll, but it's not working properly, or maybe there should be a seperate one for the LINQ element as suggested below, not sure...can anyone provide further help please?

Comment: Why are you compiling on Server?  Users will not have read/write permissions to server file system so make sure files are being save on client PC.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing your point here, but the data I want users to insert/retrieve is on a SQL server database, which is accessed via details stored in the web.config file, again this works fine when tested in visual studio; records are inserted and retrieved as expected, it's only when I publish that this falls over

Comment: Publish can mean a few different things.  You want to publish reports?  Are the reports loaded in DataBase?

Comment: Publish the website, actually it is a web project, I will correct that in the question. I'm saying when I view the page in browser from visual studio it works fine, when i publish to wwwroot folder on server and try to view in web browser, I get the compilation error

Comment: the compiler error probably means that your source code cannot find your EF model. Where is the edmx model ?  Is it in your project or in its on project. Either way it will generate a corresponding dll (CommentaryData ?) which has to be referenced in your main project.
You should make sure that when you publish, your install package includes the dll in the bin directory

Comment: You shouldn't be compiling on server.  Just running the .exe.  The only compiling that may occur if you have java code that is getting compiled.

Comment: Just checking in, have you been able to resolve you issue? If not, and issue persists, please provide feedback and I should be able to help you sort it out.

Comment: @DaniDev, no still unresolved, please see my 2nd edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally sorted this. I think the solution is worth posting; since it's taken a lot of reading to find anywhere that explicitly stated this was a necessary step:

If you are publishing via file system: After publishing you must go to IIS manager, right click your application and click 'convert to application'

This is not a necessary step with a web deploy publish as it is done for you, and it is not necessary at all with a website rather than web application, so I had simply not come across the need to do it before.

Edit: I should state that this is true for Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4.0, IIS 8. I cannot speak for other versions and it seems that this worked differently for < IIS7

Answer (score 0):

There are might be a few reasons:

1. Most likely you build you app in x32 mode and your application pool is configured to be x64, or vise versa. Make sure that your app pool and web site both are x64 or x32.
2. You referenced a library and it's not marked Copy to output like here:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, it's neither of these. System.Data.Linq was already on copy local = true. Although setting it to false also stopped it from working in Visual Studio so maybe that's not working properly on publish, it wasn't the 32/64 bit issue